# Include zero frequencies in 2-way frequency/contingency table

Tags: r, frequency, contingency

I am trying to make a contingency (frequency) table using table() in R for two integer variables, but the default option in table does not include all the values in the range for each. For example:

```
a=c(1,2,3,5)
b=c(1,1,2,3)
table(a,b)
```

returns:

```
  1 2 3
1 1 0 0
2 1 0 0 
3 0 1 0
5 0 0 1
```

I would like it to give:

```
  1 2 3
1 1 0 0
2 1 0 0 
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 0 1
```

This is a simple example where the value '4' isn't in one of the vectors. I know I could manipulate it into an array and add in a row of zero's, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to automatically do this for when the variables might span hundreds of (sparse) integer values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to get this is

```
a=factor(c(1,2,3,5), levels=1:5)
b=factor(c(1,1,2,3), levels=1:5)
table(a,b)
```

Comment: I think you just mean `table(factor(a,levels=1:5),b)`

Comment: That would be even better